# How to use virtual environment installed on Ubuntu which is installed on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, airflow, virtualenv, directed-acyclic-graphs

Recently, I've installed  airflow on Windows 10 by installing it on Ubuntu from MS Store. And I can see Airflow web-server from a browser from Windows. However, now I want to create a DAG using Pycharm on Windows, and I have to select python interpreter with airflow installed in its venv.

Where can I find this virtual environment from Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem myself. WSL is the feature of Pycharm professional edition, and there is no way to use it in the community edition.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#configure-wsl